# Do not Disturb Mode with some special conditions

Tags: automation, silent-mode

I am looking for a way to establish a "Do not Disturb" Mode (like on iOS) that does at least the following (on an unrooted phone):

- Switches ringer and notifications to Silent (disable vibrate, vol = 0) during a special time
- Lets repeated calls through (if anyone really wants to phone me)
- Still allows the alarm clock to ring
- Is disabled when phone is in use (e.g. display is active)
- Manually enableable/disableable (for a specific time)

**Cool would also be:**

- Enables only when I put the phone in the charger during the specific time
- Does not enable when connected with my car via Bluetooth

Is there any way to achieve this? If not natively, maybe by using some application? My phone and tablet are unrooted.

Comment: Its a nice question. The solution would be useful to me.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Is already pending to be re-opened. Just two more votes needed.

Comment: CyanogenMod has the feature of Audio profiles....?

Comment: @t0mm13b Audio profile won't be the solution. There are many apps in Play Store for that.

Comment: Perhaps, [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) (combined with Profile apps) can help... I am looking into it.

Comment: @SachinShekhar Ahhh... was referring to the inbuilt profiles that comes with the ROM, it may as well also be in Sammy's touchwiz interface as well... incidentally have a Acer Z130 Dual sim, and its built in, could be JB 4.2 feature, just a matter of Tasker, and switching between custom profiles..

Comment: After I sent in my Phone 'cause of a software malfunction rooting (and so Tasker) is not longer an option.
I already did that with tasker exactly as I wanted it but one feature I have used was only available on a rooted phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like [Agent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tryagent) fits the bill for you. Specifically, the Sleep Agent.

I do use the Agent app, though I don't use the Sleep Agent itself, so this list of features is just me going through the setup options in the app.

- Set Days & Times for it to activate. (defaults to 11:00 PM through 7:00 the next morning, Sunday through Thursday nights.)
- Selectable whether it does 'Silence' or 'Vibrate'.
- Has a whitelist of callers that are allowed to get through. (And selectable whether unknown callers get through or not.)
- Can wait until plugged in before starting.
- Can auto-respond with a text saying "I'm sleeping, text 'urgent' to wake me up."
- Right off your request list, it can allow repeated calls to get through.

(I use Agent mostly for the Meeting Agent: It links to the Google Calendar on my work account, and auto-silences the phone for the duration of the meeting.)

Answer (score 1):

[Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) is a great tool! It receives GSM tower ID and learns your locations (home, work, school) so you can set which profile to turn at specific location at specific time.

Best feature is that it's NOT a battery drainer.